# How to play mp3 file using Jquery in android PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i want to play mp3 file in background using jQuery in android phoneGap, i have included cordova-2.2.0.js with jquery-1.9.0.js file .. here is my html code. what i am doing wrong while i have given all permissions in Manifest File

here is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>First App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap</h1>
       <h2>Edit assets/www/index.html</h2>
    <script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>   
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script> 
    <script>


$(document).ready(function(){
            alert("hey");
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.src = "audio.mp3";
            audio.play();
        });

  </script>
  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: why are you using so outdated version of cordova, current version is 3.5!!

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741114/unable-to-play-an-audio-mp3-file-in-phonegap-android) link, use media instead of audio

```
var myaudio = new Media('/android_asset/www/audio/file.mp3');
```

for Your Error **Attempt to call getDuration without valid media player**

try this links

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/aa_2dHjy9C0

http://www.anddev.org/multimedia-problems-f28/mediaplayer-attempt-to-call-getduration-without-t51386.html

[Android: attempt to call getduration without a valid mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710922/android-attempt-to-call-getduration-without-a-valid-mediaplayer)

http://maffelu.net/phonegap-attempt-call-getduration-without-valid-mediaplayer/

i am saying to check this link bacause you have not posted the android code so try it.

Hope this will help.

Comment: its also not playing the audio

Comment: is any other permission i have to give in config.xml file

Comment: check the link that i have posted in my answer.

Comment: try just replacing this `var audio = new Audio();` to `var myaudio = new Media('src');` this should help.

Comment: have you checked that link & tried to replace `Media` instead of `Audio` ?

Comment: still not done.. error: Attempt to call getDuration without valid media player

Comment: i am running my app in emulator.. can it play audio or i have to install this app in my cellphone

Comment: try testing in cellphone.You might be calling getDuration before the file is fully loaded. is it ?

Comment: have you written something like this `int duration = video.getDuration();` ? & check this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710922/android-attempt-to-call-getduration-without-a-valid-mediaplayer`

Comment: no sir i just written the what i mentioned in my question

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("hey");
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.src = "audio.mp3";
            audio.play();
        });

Comment: can u plz help me to send me small source code playing audio in android phonegap.. please

Comment: sorry i can't but check my updated answer. i have posted all the links for ERROR you are getting.

Comment: bcz audio is playing correctly in my browser but its not in phonegap android

Comment: should i have to give any permission in any xml file file

Comment: yes... `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` & `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`